# Finding roots of $2x^3-5x^2+18x+45$

Tags: polynomials, roots

solve $2x^3-5x^2+18x+45$
not exactly sure where to start on finding the zeros complex or real. There is one real zero and two complex I know that from graphing just cannot do it on paper to understand it.

Comment: The sign of $45$ (or $-5x^2$) is off, otherwise you could factor by grouping.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: HInt:  first search for rational roots.  As you have graphed the function already, you should have a pretty good idea of the value already.

Answer (score 1):

You can remark that $\frac{-3}{2}=-1.5$ is a solution.

Comment: Nor -1 nor 5 are zeros.

Comment: i mean $\frac{-3}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

From Hamza's post one solution is -1.5,others you can find dividing polynomial to the $(x+1.5)$,then we get:
$$2x^{ 3 }-5x^{ 2 }+18x+45=0\\ \left( x+1.5 \right) \left( 2x^{ 2 }-8x+30 \right) =0\\ \left( x+1.5 \right) \left( x^{ 2 }-4x+15 \right) =0\\ { x }_{ 1 }=-1.5,x_{ 2 }=2+i\sqrt { 11 } ,{ x }_{ 3 }=2-i\sqrt { 11 } $$

Comment: I think that the second and the third solution will be $2\pm i \sqrt{11}$